# Typescript: Public or Private for refactored/service method?

Tags: angular, typescript, private

**Goal**: I have a method on my component that will be used in multiple components, so I would like to refactor it to another class(e.g. a service class).

**Background**: This method takes a date of birth that the user enters on a profile form and then reformats it back to MM/DD/YYYY (assuming that they entered it in as DD/MM/YYYY).

**Question**: If I move the method to the service class, should it still be public or private?

I've tried looking this up but it is not entirely clear. It sounds like people are saying keep it public unless the method is in the same class it is being used.

**Current**

Component:

```
let dobForDb = this.formatDateForDB("31/12/2019");

formatDateForDB(data: any): string {
        // Separate by '/'
        var array = data.split("/");
        let day = array[0];
        let month = array[1];
        let year = array[2];
        let dateString = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
        return dateString;
    }
```

***Would become***

Component:

```
let dobForDb = this.serviceclass.formatDateForDB("31/12/2019");
```

Service Class:

```
public formatDateForDB(data: any): string {
        // Separate by '/'
        var array = data.split("/");
        let day = array[0];
        let month = array[1];
        let year = array[2];
        let dateString = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
        return dateString;
    }
```

Comment: There's not a whole lot of information to go on here; not clear why you want it to be `private` at all.  If you refactor this way, `formateDateforDB()` should not be a `private` member of your service class, but you might want the `serviceclass` property of your component to be a `private` property.  Consider editing the code here to constitute a [mcve] as described in [ask], ideally so that it can be dropped into a standalone IDE like [The Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @jcalz DOB is identifying information which is why I was considering making it private

Answer (score 2):

If you declare a method in a service that you eventually want to use in a component, that method would need to be public. Otherwise, you simply won't be able to use the method in a different class (e.g. component class). Try it yourself: declare a method in a service as private:

```
private doSomething()
```

...and you won't be able to access it in a component where the service is injected.

So in your case the methods need to be public.

Also, in typescript all [properties and methods are public by default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#public-by-default), so `public` modifier is redundant (whether to use it or not is a question of project/personal conventions). So both of these methods are public:

```
doSomething() {}

public doSomething() {}
```

You only declare a method as private if it's only meant to be used within the same class, and not outside of it. This includes usage in component templates: private methods and properties of a component class are not available to the component's template.

Comment: As a note, also adding that if you want to compile a build with `aot: true` then you shouldn't use private members that are accessed within the template (it loses type-checking). At least, not until Ivy comes in.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:** don't use private/public except for dependency injection.

This question is mostly opinion based tho.
Personnaly, I NEVER set public or private my properties & methods, the only way I use `private` is for dependency injection e.g.

```
constructor(private foo: FooService) { }
```

For me it make no sense to set a property/method as private, even worse the case where there are setters & getters.

I mean I use TypeScript for types so the code is easier/cleaner and adding theses keywords just make the code disgusting, who care a property is private or public, 
I'm tall enough to know what I can touch in applications.

It make more sense to make a property readonly.